# How does the Sidearm™ cricket ball thrower work?

Tags: cricket, equipment

I have seen the videos where Graham Gooch is able to do easy throwdowns for batting practice - fast deliveries, slower ones, off-spinners, leg-spinners.

Can you tell me how and when the ball is released from the sidearm? Is the sidearm merely a cup holder for the ball and the ball is just flung at the batsman? (similar to a trebuchet probably?)
Or, does the sidearm *clutch* the ball and release it on a button press/release on the handle of the sidearm?

About [Sidearm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJO2yaqNesk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially a cup with curved sides that provide a degree of grip to the ball.  The action of flicking the Sidearm at the batsman gives the ball enough momentum of it's own to break out of the cup and head to the batsman on it's own.  It's developed from a device used by dog owners to throw tennis balls.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? And also does this mean that with wear and tear, the sidearm will get useless?

Comment: No, I've seen a few around so this is just personal observation.  The cup is made of a reasonably strong plastic so I guess it would last a while but yes wear and tear would eventually reduce its effectiveness.